# Masking Processing with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mask, masking

I'm going to mask words with regex.

The detection results are as follows.

```
regex: (?<=.{2}).*(?=.{3})
word : AABBCCC
Result : BB
```

Use the following code to function normally as shown below.

```
word.match(new RegExp(regex, 'gi')).forEach(v => {
    word = word.replace(v, '*'.repeat(v.length));
});
```

Result: AA**CCC

But If the word is BBBBCCC, Result is **BBCCC
I want to BB**CCC, How can I get the results I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the foreach, you are replacing the match `BB` (which is in variable `v`) in the word `BBBBCCC`, which will replace the first occurrence of `BB` giving `**BBCCC`

It works in the first example for `AABBCCC` as `BB` is the only occurrence in the string to be replaced.

What you can to is use the match in the callback of replace.

```js
let word = "BBBBCCC";
const regex = /(?<=.{2}).+(?=.{3})/;
console.log(word.replace(regex, v => '*'.repeat(v.length)))
```